# $u$-substitution failure in finding $f'(x)$ where $ f(x) = \int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}\, dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I'm practicing for the GRE exam, and came across the following question: If
$$
f(x) = \int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}\, dt,
$$
find $f'(x)$. The answer given is $\frac{1}{x}(1 - 2\cos(x^2))$, and I see how they get that answer. What I'm wondering is why the following $u$-substitution gives the wrong answer (or perhaps I'm making a mistake somewhere):

If we set $u = xt$, then the integral transforms to 
$$
f(x) = \int_{x^2}^0 \frac{\cos(u)}{u}\, du,
$$
which means that $f'(x) = -(\cos(x^2)/x^2)(2x) = -\cos(x^2)/x$, which misses the $1/x$ term which the answer key says we should have.

I cannot see where I am making a mistake in the $u$-sub; is it invalid in this case? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is not well-defined. For no $x$ is $\frac{\cos (xt)}{t}$ integrable at $0$.

Comment: This cannot be correct.  Perhaps $f(x)=\int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)-1}{t}\,dt$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You suppose  the upper bound of the integral is  -1. Now what's wrong with that substitution ?

Comment: @Redshoes You mean defining $f(x)$ as $\int_x^{-1} \frac{\cos (xt)}{t}\,dt$ for $x < 0$? Then there's nothing wrong with transforming it into $\int_{x^2}^{-x} \frac{\cos u}{u}\,du$ via $u = xt$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now differentiate the both integrals in terms of $x$. Do you get same functions ?

Comment: @Redshoes Let's see. The original yields $$\int_x^{-1} -\sin (xt)\,dt - \frac{\cos (x^2)}{x} = \frac{\cos (xt)}{x}\biggr\rvert_{x}^{-1} - \frac{\cos (x^2)}{x} = \frac{\cos (-x)}{x} - 2\frac{\cos (x^2)}{x}\,.$$ The transformed integral yields $$\frac{\cos (-x)}{-x}\cdot (-1) - \frac{\cos (x^2)}{x^2}\cdot 2x = \frac{\cos (-x)}{x} - 2\frac{\cos (x^2)}{x}\,.$$ Yes, I get the same derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I was just wondering :)

Comment: Is this from Princeton? Princeton has several errata

Answer (score 2):

First, the integral $\int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)}{t}\,dt$ fails to exist.

So instead, suppose $f(x)$ be given by the integral

$$f(x)=\int_x^0 \frac{\cos(xt)-1}{t}\,dt$$

Then, we have from Leibniz's Rule

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{1-\cos(x^2)}{x}+\int_0^x \sin(xt)\,dt\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{1-\cos(x^2)}{x}\right)
\end{align}$$